# Example task for BRNN (bidirectional recurrent neural network)

Tags: networking

I have to implement and train BRNN (bidirectional recurrent neural network). The problem is I have no idea what this network should do.

First of all, I would like to ask if this task is good for RNN: from weight, length and etc. classify if person is adult or child.

Is this task ok for BRNN as well? I am not sure, because I don't see here any sense of using backward states. So what task would be good for such network? I was thinking about something like this: provide 12...45 and insert appropiate number (in this case it would be 3). Anyway I don't have idea how to do it with BRNN.

I was thinking about representing numbers as vectors. For example:
1 = 00001, 2 = 00010, 3 = 00100, 4 = 01000, 5 = 10000, Unknown = 00000

Let's say we know there is 12...45 and the number in the middle is not known, so the BRNN have to recognize it. Do I think good there will be 5 epoches? And the input neuron group will have 5 neurons (one neuron for one bit of vector)? What would be the ouput? The "00100" in the 3rd epoch? How to provide input data? "00001" in 1st epoch, "00010" in 2nd epoch, "00000" in third epoch and etc.?